# PHP - with require_once/include/require, the path is relative to what?

Tags: php, path

when on `"index.php"`, I do `require_once("/all_fns.php")`.

`"all_fns.php"` itself requires files with paths relative to `all_fns.php` (itself).

My question is, should I write the paths on all_fns relative to all_fns.php or to index.php?

This is all very confusing to me and wanted to get it straight.

Comment: As a side note, "/all_fns.php" is an *absolute* path that will look for a file in the OS's root directory (on a non-Windows system)

Comment: On a Windows system as well. It will search in the current drive's root.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are treated as relative to `index.php`.

If you need to reference a file relative to the include, use

```
__DIR__."/relative/file.php";
```

Comment: This worked for me when I wanted a relative path. require_once('../bla.php'); would not work. require_once(\_\_DIR\_\_.'/../bla.php'); works.

Comment: @AlixAxel `dirname(__FILE__)` is needed on older PHP versions.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: Yes, but the OP hasn't stated that he's using a *very* old PHP version, we can assume that he's using the latest stable release.

Comment: @AlixAxel so newest version is assumed?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: Not the newest, but the latest stable one (give or take 6 months for server packages to catch up - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5), `__DIR__` was stable since 30-Jun-2009. Either way, the answer and the comment still provide both options, I just think we shouldn't be advocating prehistoric code. But then again, SourceForge kept supporting PHP 3.X for a terribly long time.

Answer (score 2):

They are relative to the [getcwd()](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

Comment: Updated link: [getcwd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

Answer (score 0):

in index.php define some directories

```
define ( 'INCLUDES_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
define ( 'INCLUDES_DIR2', INCLUDES_DIR . '/some_directory' );
```

then in all the other files you can use `INCLUDES_DIR`

```
include( INCLUDES_DIR1 . 'file.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Either Use

```
echo  in_get( "include_path") ;
```

Or open up your ini file and find out what your ini path is, and put your include file in THAT DIRECTORY (or one of those directories) and release yourself from worrying about absolute/relative include problems forever.

Comment: There isn't a function called `in_get()`. Do you mean `ini_get()`?