# PHP - Relative paths "require"

Tags: php, url, path, require, relative-path

My directory structure looks like this:

```
blog -> admin -> index.php
blog.php
db.php
functions.php
```

I have been trying to `include` (`require`, really) `blog.php` in the `admin/index.php`, but facing lots of errors. I'm following a PHP course, and the instructor does the same thing successfully.

admin/index.php:

```
require "../blog.php";
```

which, in turn, requires two more files in its directory.

```
require "db.php";
require "functions.php";
```

Comment: I think you need to just step it out a level, ie. `../../blog.php` assuming that `blog.php` is not in the `blog` folder.

Comment: I don't think that would work. `blog.php` is in the `blog` directory.

Comment: Ahh your notation of directory structure was confusing to me :-)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you find that relative include paths aren't working as expected, a quick fix is to prepend `__DIR__` to the front of the path you're trying to include.

```
require __DIR__ . "/../blog.php";
```

It's reasonably clean, and you don't need to modify the include path or working directory.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Though I have no idea why do I have to do this. The instructor gets away with `require "../blog.php";` without any problem. Is it because of OS differences? He's on Mac, and I am on Windows.

Comment: I'm actually not entirely sure - I believe it has to do with the current working directory not always matching the script's directory.

Comment: @Rafay: its a bad practice anyway. You should always calculate the absolute path and then require/include.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) in your php.ini.

If you want to set it at run-time, use [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).

Answer (score 2):

If you are including this files `db.php and functions.php` in `index.php` then you have to write this code

```
require "../db.php";
require "../functions.php";
```

OR if you are including this files in `blog.php` then write this code

```
require "db.php";
require "functions.php";
```

Answer (score -3):

I like to start my files with `chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`. This allows me to get a nice and logical base path for all my includes.

Comment: That's why you have the include_path directive in the php.ini.

Comment: `include_path` doesn't apply for things like `file_exists` though ;)

Comment: and one file operation per php file with no real use. Consider using PSR-0 or using __DIR__.