# Fatal error : require(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, path

So, I have a directory and the sub like this

```
+task
  +Include  
    +vendor  
     - autoload.php

  +Theme  
    +action
     - doInsert.php
    +objects
     - CardAccessor.php
```

And the error appeared when I try to call the `autoload.php` in `CardAccessor.php`

doInsert.php

```
require_once '../objects/CardAccessor.php';
```

CardAccessor.php

```
require '/../include/vendor/autoload.php';
```

The error said :

> Warning: require(/../include/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/../include/vendor/autoload.php'

Comment: The file `/../include/vendor/autoload.php` does not exist.

Comment: try `require '../../Include/vendor/autoload.php';` with a capital I in `Include`.

Answer (score 0):

`require '/../include/vendor/autoload.php'` won't work, you'll need to take the first slash off. As it is written, the first slash tells it to go to the root directory, then go up one from there (which it can't do, it's already at the root).

Given your directory structure, I believe that `require '../../include/vendor/autoload.php'` should work.

Comment: I already try ../include/vendor/autoload.php, still do not work

Comment: I just looked again at the directory structure. You'll need to go up two levels, ie ../../include/vendor/autoload.php. I'm editing my answer to match.

Answer (score 0):

When you do an `include`, the path is always relative to the file that include the file.

What you need to put is `require '../../Include/vendors/autoload.php'` or set the full path like `require '/my/project/path/task/Include/vendor/autoload.php'`.

This is revelant to your problem : [PHP - Relative paths "require"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898894/php-relative-paths-require#13898946)

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a config

if this is linux unix use

```
$baseDir = "/base/dir"; //to define where in the root filesys where youre scripts and assets live
```

then use

```
$baseDir."/task/Include" or 
$baseDir."/task/Theme/objects/CardAccessor.php" or 
$baseDir."/task/include/vendor/autoload.php"
```

or you can create

```
$sourceDir = $baseDir."/task/";
```

this is also used for portability, if you decide to move the source you can modify the config; in addition, this is an efficient way to include or require files in your scripts.