# PHP file path error for autoloader

Tags: php, filepath, require-once

Here is my file structure on my cpanel webserver

```
root
   > vendor
         > autoload.php
   > public_html
         > folder
               > file2.php
         > script_folder
               > include_file.php
         > file1.php
```

Inside include_file.php I have

```
 require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
```

file1.php and file2.php both contain the same call to include_file.php

```
 require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/script_folder/include_file.php");
```

This works fine when I run file1.php but when I run file2.php i receive the following error message.

> No such file or directory Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/pear') in /lvl1/lvl2/public_html/script_folder/include_file.php

However, if I change `require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');` to `require_once('../../vendor/autoload.php');` in include_file.php then file2.php works and file1.php does not work.  It showes a similar error.

I understand this is a file path issue but, what I don't understand is why.  Shouldn't the path in `include_file.php` always be the same no matter what file is calling it; i.e. file1.php or file2.php?

The way I see it is the the actual require_once statement is being called from include_file.php but, the behavior I'm seeing makes me think the require_once statement is being ran from file1.php or file2.php resulting in the filepath error.

Can someone please clarify?

---

UPDATE:   inside include_file.php I have tried using:

`require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/vendor/autoload.php');`

and

`require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php');`

neither of these work since both return `public_html` as the main working directory.  My `vendor` folder is outside the main working directory.

what is returned is this:

`/script_folder/vendor/autoload.php`

I understand I can simply include the correct file path at the beginning of `file1.php` and `file2.php` but, I was trying to figure out a way to reduce the number of requires I need in each file to only one by pointing them to `include_file.php`, then letting `include_file.php` do the rest of the work.

My `include_file.php` file contains several other require statements to other scripts on my server.  Kind of like a mini autoloader.  All of the other require statements work fine except the `autoload.php` one I'm having trouble with here.

The only difference I can see is my other scripts are within my `public_html` folder and my `autoload.php` file is located outside of `public_html`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP require() relative path error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954578/php-require-relative-path-error)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to work perfectly.  Guess instead of a relative path I need to use the absolute path.

include_file.php:

```
$autoload = str_replace('public_html','vendor/autoload.php',$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
include($autoload);
```

it allows me to call:

`require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/script_folder/include_file.php");`

from any files that are in my public_html folder.

---

in include_file.php `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` returns `/lvl1/lvl2/public_html` (the full server path to the publicly visible folder)

then I replace `public_html` with the the path to my autoloader `vendor/autoload.php`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Composer, you only need to require "autoload.php" once in `file1.php` and the file should contain a namespace like `namespace App;` at the top of the file below the opening PHP tag. Subsequently, `file2.php` should contain `namespace App\folder;` and `included_file.php` should contain `namespace App\script_folder;`.

The namespace should also be defined in `composer.json` like so:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "public_html/"
    }
}
```