# PHP (wordpress): why do I need dirname(__FILE__) to use relative paths?

Tags: php, wordpress, relative-path

If I include files with

`include('test.php');`

it works, but when I try to include it using relative paths

`include('./test.php');`

It doesn't, as neither it does if I try to include files from parent folders

`include('../test.php');` (once moved the file)

I am on Windows, so I tested just in case

`include('.\test.php');`

`include('.\\test.php');`

But got the same failed result (failed to open stream: No such file or directory)

*This is executing this within a wordpress plugin

---

Then this works if using

`include(dirname(__FILE__) . './test.php');`

Why? What's the reasoning?

Comment: When you use a ./test.php it's assuming you meant the front-end controller, which is your original index.php, not the file which are are currently in.

Comment: as an alternative you could use `__DIR__ . '/test.php'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954578/php-require-relative-path-error

Comment: Thanks to both, now it's clear :)