# How to use 'include' and 'require' in a new folder from the main one?

Tags: php

I have written `config.php`, `head.php` in my `public_html`, now i need them in the new folder (`public_html/test/gallery`) where test is a sub-domain using `require` and `include` respectively.

```
<?php
require_once"../config.php";
require_once"../func.php";
include_once"../head.php";
echo "are u mad";
?>
```

It keeps returning a blank page. How do I do that?

Comment: You can put paths into the include directives... `include('../whatever.php')`

Comment: Read up on include and require in the php manual? How about that?

Comment: try: `require_once"../../config.php"` Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Does it have something to do with the missing `( )` around `../config.php`? **Note** I only ask because I have only used `require()` with the brackets.

Comment: @TimLewis No it does not, it's the same with echo, you could do `echo ("xy");` but you also can do `echo "xy";` (Also see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - with require\_once/include/require, the path is relative to what?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954750/php-with-require-once-include-require-the-path-is-relative-to-what)

Comment: in which page you are calling the above and where is it located in your site?

Comment: Warning: require(../../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/peaksmso/public_html/test/gallery/gallery.php on line 12

Warning: require(../../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/peaksmso/public_html/test/gallery/gallery.php on line 12

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../../config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/peaksmso/public_html/test/gallery/gallery.php on line 12

Comment: @ Aram Tchekrekjian, it is located in /public_html/test i.e /public_html/config.php I need it in /public_html/test/gallery/gallery.php

Comment: @rm-vanda, explain well please, am new in php, I don't understand You quite well

Comment: Not clear, come down to my level please

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute paths always, and you'll never bang your head like this again.

```
include_once "/var/www/path/to/your/script.php";
```

And also, you can debug this much more effectively if you put the following at the top of your pages which you are having trouble with:

```
ini_set("display_errors","On");
error_reporting(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to include all files relative to the document root like so:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/depends/where/code/is.php";
```

the good thing is that all files will be in relation to one source root.
This makes your code more like fluid!

*Tip: you can also specify an include path in your php.ini config file.  This helps PHP find your file faster too.